# Using the definition of sqrt(x)

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I am having trouble understanding what the definition of $\sqrt{x}$ is. I guess it's $x = a^2$ where $a$ is an integer. The question asks for:

Use the exact definition of $\sqrt{x}$ to prove that $x \leq y$ implies $\sqrt{x} \leq \sqrt{y}$.

It sounds too simple enough for me: Let $x=a^2$ and $y=b^2$ where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers.

Then from our assumption, $x \leq y$ we have $a^2 \leq b^2$ or $a \leq b$. Since $a \leq b$, thus $\sqrt{x} \leq \sqrt{y}$. Does this make sense?

Comment: It would, if you could justify $a^2\leq b^2\implies a\leq b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you need to prove that if $a$ and $b$ are positive, then $$a^2 \leq b^2 \implies a \leq b$$ Note that $$a^2 \leq b^2 \implies (b^2 - a^2) \geq 0 \implies (b+a)(b-a) \geq 0$$
Now since $a$ and $b$ are positive, we have $a+b > 0$. Hence, $b-a \geq 0$, which gives us what we want.

Answer (score 0):

> I am having trouble understanding what the definition of $\sqrt{x}$ is. I guess it's $x=a^2$ where $a$ is an integer.

It sounds like you understand square roots just fine, but I think you may want $x$ to be nonnegative, i.e., $x\geq0$, and you want $a$ to be a real number.  Otherwise, the discussion becomes a little more complicated.

> Then from our assumption, $x\leq y$ we have $a^2\leq b^2$ or $a\leq b$.

This is fine, but there's a big step between $a^2\leq b^2$ and $a\leq b$.  How do you know that applying the square root to both sides of the inequality preserves the inequality?  Is this related to what you're trying to show?

Try this instead.  Suppose at least one of $x$ and $y$ are nonzero.  Then
\begin{align*}
x\leq y 
&\Longrightarrow x-y\leq0\\
&\Longrightarrow \left(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}\right)\left(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}\right)\leq0\\
&\Longrightarrow \sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}\leq 0\\
&\Longrightarrow \sqrt{x}\leq\sqrt{y}.
\end{align*}
What did we do at each step?  First, we subtracted $y$ from both sides of the inequality.  Second, we "factored" $x-y$.  Third, we divided both sides of the inequality by $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}$, which is positive by assuming that at least one of $x$ and $y$ aren't zero, so we didn't divide by zero or change the sign of the inequality.  Fourth, we added $\sqrt{y}$ to both sides of the inequality.  Alternatively, if both $x$ and $y$ are zero, then the inequality is satisfied trivially.

Depending on what your definition is for $\sqrt{x}$, you can change the proof accordingly.  If $\sqrt{x}$ is defined as the nonnegative number $a$ satisfying $x=a^2$, then you can replace $x$ with $a^2$ and $\sqrt{x}$ with $a$ (as well as $y$ with $b^2$ and $\sqrt{y}$ with $b$) in each step of the above proof to use the definition.

Comment: On the second line is there a reason your sign changes from less than to equal to 0? And on the fourth line, you added sqrt(y) to both sides, not y.

Comment: In addition, you don't use the exact definition of sqrt(x) for your solution.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the two small typos.  I've fixed them.  Also, I've changed your definition to something a little more accurate and used it in the proof.